# Multi part identifier cannot be bound (INSERT statement)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to copy values from column in table in one database to a column in a table in a different database.

The code is:

```
USE TargetDatabase
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.TargetTable(field1)
   SELECT field1
     FROM SourceDatabase.dbo.SourceTable
     WHERE (SourceTable.ID= TargetTable.ID)
```

I am getting the

> Multi part identifier cannot be bound

error on `TargetTable.ID`.

I have used `dbo.TargetTable.ID` and I get the same error.

If I use just `ID`, I get Invalid column name `ID` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want an `update`:

```
UPDATE tt
   SET field1 = st.field1
   FROM dbo.TargetTable tt JOIN
        SourceDatabase.dbo.SourceTable st 
        ON st.ID = tt.ID;
```

`INSERT` inserts new rows, with values for the columns.  `UPDATE` updates column values in existing rows.

Answer (score 0):

Using `EXISTS` to refer to the `TargetTable`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TargetTable(field1)
    SELECT field1
    FROM SourceDatabase.dbo.SourceTable
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TargetTable WHERE SourceTable.ID = TargetTable.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
USE TargetDatabase
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.TargetTable(field1)
   SELECT field1 
     FROM SourceDatabase.dbo.SourceTable inner join dbo.TargetTable on 
     SourceTable.ID= TargetTable.ID
```